# Factory_girl data is not being cleaned up

Tags: factory-bot

I am using factory girl for test data. I create a user object in a before(:each) block, and it runs through a few expectations just fine. If i run the tests again, the validation on the model fail because they require a unique username. The test data from the previous run is still there. I know a cleanup task is required when using before(:all), but since im using before(:each), does it not get cleaned up?

Comment: Do you have   config.use_transactional_fixtures = true in your spec_helper.rb?

Comment: Yep, still having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with how I was using factory girl objects, and my tests. In some of the tests, other rows were being written to the database. I stubbed out some of the create calls, and also fixed up how I was using the factory girl objects.